# Getting Error :/usr/bin/python: No module named thrift_compiler

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, thrift

I am trying to run a simple thrift communication using cpp in ubuntu 16.04.my thrift folder is in usr/local/, and my thrift.pc file is in usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.my python folder both 2.7 and 3.5 version are in usr/local/lib  folder.
I am following this site for  creating a simple client server communication
http://www.avabodh.com/thrift/client_server.html

so i have written a simple calculator.thrift file 
code

```
namspace cpp example
service Calculator
{
    i64 add(1:i32 num1, 2:i32 num2);
}
```

in my home folder and run

```
python -m thrift_compiler.main --gen cpp2 calculator.thrift
```

I am getting this error when i am going to generate  gen-cpp2 folder which contains all generated cpp files

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named thrift_compiler
```

my thrift server version is 0.9.3. I am very new with thrift protocol.kindly help me to figure out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC the python-based compiler has been removed from the sources a while ago. [Here's](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/py) the official Python tutorial which should also work with the rather old version 0.9.3

In a nutshell, you need to `make install` the Thrift compiler, then run it as described in the tutorial to generate the code from the IDL:

```
thrift  --gen cpp  calculator.thrift
```

To get more info about cmdline parameters type

```
thrift  --help
```